# Jmeter cmdrunner observed garbage characters

Tags: linux, jenkins, graph, jmeter, centos

Please need some advise how to resolve this characters, thanks.

command:

```
java -jar apache-jmeter-4.0/lib/cmdrunner-2.2.jar --tool Reporter --generate-png tps_L1.png --input-jtl jmeter.jtl --plugin-type TransactionsPerSecond --width 1024 --height 768
```

Environment:

```
CentOS v7.3
Jmeter v4.0
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please edit your question and improve the description of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by your test using non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters for [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)(s) and [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)(s) labels.

1. First of all double check JMeter doesn't have problems with storing/interpreting Thread Group and Sampler labels, i.e. try generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) (it includes Transactions per Second chart by the way)

   [image: JMeter dashboard tps]
2. If the problem remains - you need to find a way to configure JMeter to handle national characters, i.e. try explicitly defining [`file.encoding`](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html) property to be `UTF-8`. To do this add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   file.encoding=UTF-8
   ```

   and restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. If it helps - play the same trick with JMeter Plugins CMDRunner tool, like:

   ```
   java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar apache-jmeter-4.0/lib/cmdrunner-2.2.jar --tool Reporter --generate-png tps_L1.png --input-jtl jmeter.jtl --plugin-type TransactionsPerSecond --width 1024 --height 768
   ```

---

Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever the latest version is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible